# Heat loss from hot cast iron oven

Tags: thermodynamics

I am considering an unconventional pizza oven made from cast iron. What is a good formula for estimating non-radiative heat loss from a 450C/850F surface in a 20C outdoor environment?

I am looking for something like http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/steel-pipes-heat-loss-d_53.html but for higher temperatures.